# How to remove the views while using the properties from the context of outerview in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a scenerio in which i wanted to render some properties in the child view with the properties of the parent view but on the basis of some properties. But when the properties evaluates to false the view should be destroyed but its giving error as:
 cannot call unchain of undefined and some errors also related to this.

code:

**Template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

  {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="address">
  {{item.Address.addressline1}}<br />
  {{item.Address.addressLine2}}<br />
  {{item.Address.city}}, {{item.Address.state}}<br />
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{#if addressVisible}}
  <button {{action hideAddress}}> Hide Address </button>
  {{else}}
  <button {{action showAddress}}>Show Address</button>
  {{/if}}

  <ul>
  {{#each item in model}}
    <li>
      {{item.name}}<br />
      {{#if addressVisible}}
      {{view App.AddressView}}
      {{/if}}
    </li>

  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

I have created a fiddle to show my issue: 
http://jsbin.com/inoroj/5/edit
When we click on showAddress it shows all the address views but when clicked on hide all views should hide, but instead it raises unchain error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for some reason Ember did not like your property being capitalized. By changing `Address` to `address` the app worked as expected. I made a few other small changes as well.

http://jsbin.com/uquyuv/1/edit

Comment: Is capitilization a problem in emberjs because the responses from the service are normally capitilized and how can we resolve this issue.